# SQL Structure, Dynamic Two Columns or Unique Colmuns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I'm not sure which is faster. I have the need to store lists of possible data.

Currently I have an SQL table with the following structure being accessed with php.

```
boxID
place
name  -- (serialNum, itemNum, idlock, etc, etc)
data
--(Note: The Primary Key here would be boxId, place, name, and data, to prevent duplicate data.)
```

The reason i set it up like this was to prevent creating columns per named data. Its a possibility in the future to have 5-10 different named data or more. Also possible to store 1,000 - 10,000 entries of data in one week for just one named data. It will be searched as well, like when i get place from a specific serialNum, then getting all data related to that place. (A specific serialNum, itemNum, idLock, etc, etc,)

**But my concern is that my structure could be slower than just creating a named column for each named data. For example:**

```
boxID
place
serialNum
itemNum
idLock
etc
etc
--(Note: Not even sure how to add keys to this if i would do it this way)
```

**To sum it up: Which is faster and better practice?** (keep in mind im still a novice with SQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to model your data as entities with specific attributes.  Typically an entity has at most a few dozen attributes.  The entities typically turn into tables, and the attributes typically which turn into columns.  That is, the physical model and the logic model are often very similar.

There may be other considerations.  For instance, there is a limit on the number of columns a row can have -- and if you have more columns, you need another solution.  Similarly, if the data is sparse (that is, most values are NULL), then having lots of unused columns may be a waste of space.  That is, it is more efficient to store it in another format.  SQL Server offers sparse columns for this reason.

My suggestion is that you design your table in an intuitive way with named columns.  A volume of data of 1,000 - 10,000 rows per week is not that much data.  That turns into 50,000 - 500,000 rows per year, which SQL Server should be easily able to handle the volume.  You don't say how many named entities you have, but table with millions or tens of millions of rows are quite reasonable for modern databases.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by entities, but the data is usually added per box. And a box could contain anywhere from 50-600 items. Each having numbers or information needed for later down the line of this business. Also, the items are considerd different, but mostly should be the same

Comment: @TrinaryAtom . . . If you are going to use databases, you should be familiar with the term:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model.